# how to set angle between points of a bezier curve

Tags: unity

[image]

From the bezier curve image above, how can I set the angle `r` manually, so that changing it does not affect the distance between `A` and `B`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Form the direction the tangent should point when the angle is zero.
var zeroAngleDirection = (D - A).normalized;

// Compute a rotation by the desired angle, clockwise about the positive z axis.
var twist = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, -angle);

// Set point B a desired distance away from A, in the rotated direction.
B = A + twist * zeroAngleDirection * desiredLength;
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I created a slider for changing the angle (which is positive or negative) from the inspector editor. When I manually move the control points around (using the mouse in the scene view) I use `Vector2.Angle` to update the slider angle value. But `Vector2.Angle` always gives positive angles. How can I get the angle values of `Vector2.Angle` to coincide (positive and negative) with that of the code above?

Comment: You might want to use Mathf.Atan2 instead.

Comment: I used  `Mathf.Atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * 180 / Mathf.PI;` but it's also only giving me positive values

Comment: Make sure you're measuring the angle you mean to. You want the difference in the angle between vector AD and vector AB. So `Mathf.DeltaAngle(Mathf.Rad2Deg * Mathf.Atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x), Mathf.Rad2Deg * Mathf.Atan2(p4.y-p1.y, p4.x-p1.x))` Possibly negated? Or you can use your Vector2.Angle approach and recover the sign by checking whether B is to the right or to the left of D relative to A.

Comment: This might seem simple but it's beating me. Say from the above diagram I want to move `D` using your solution with the direction still `var zeroAngleDirection = (D - A).normalized;`. How should I make a "copy" or get the original value of `D`? I made a slider that I use to change the angle in the editor class so the value of D is always being updated.

Comment: You can take a copy of `D` just by writing `Vector3 dCopy = D`, so I think I must not be understanding what you're asking for. Try posting a new question diagramming what you need.